# Opening 6000+ URLs at once on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download

I've seen batch URL downloaders, though they don't work with me due to the amount of URLs I need to open at once. All the URLs that I have are direct download links as well, which makes it worse with those programs.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p1AX_ELfk_ssFEfX9uny5YRdoxeana3JIt1baepf3bU/edit?usp=sharing) is a complete list of all the URLs that I need to batch open. Any help would be much appreciated.

Downloading all of these at once would speed up the process a lot instead of pasting down the URLs one by one.

Comment: Why do you need to open 6,000 URLs at once?!?!?

Comment: You will break the internet pipes.

Comment: @Ren You could use powershell to iterate through the list of URLs and then call invoke-webrequest method to download the items

Comment: Why do direct download links make it worse? That only makes it better imo.

Comment: Are you sure you want to _open_ all those URLs? I can see the need to download a lot but why do you want to display so many at one time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late, but the root of my problems with wget not working is due to the fact that I use Windows 10. I would have to type in `CMD` first in Powershell in order for wget to actually work. Then I can finally use `wget -i text_file_name.txt` for it to download all the files from the links.

Answer (score 3):

I'd strongly advise you against opening all these URLs in any browser. There are two simple solutions depending on which operating system you use:

## Linux:

Assuming you have `links.txt`, one direct-link per line, run the following bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir downloaded_files
while read -r line; do
    wget "$line"
done < links.txt
```

## Windows:

The [jDownloader2](http://www.jdownloader.org/jdownloader2) tool sounds like exactly what you need. Install it, open it, go to `LinkGrabber`:
[image]

Then hit `Add New Links` on the bottom, and paste your list of URLs in the textbox:
[image]

Once you pressed `Continue` jDownloader will check the availability of those links. After that you simply hit the ▶️ button on the top left to start your downloads.

Note: I am in no way affiliated with the mentioned software. I love it though.

Comment: Powershell: `Get-Content .\links.txt | %{ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -OutFile $_.split("/")[-1] }`

Comment: I use Windows. Sadly, jDownloader2 didn't work for me.
I'm trying to figure out how to get wget working though, since it can apparently do that. However, I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Comment: @Ren Have you tried the powershell command bcs78 provided? Why does jDownloader2 not work for you? Where are the "troubles"?

Comment: @confetti Just tried the powershell command right now. Gave me an error saying that my file (Sprite-urls.txt) isn't found. As for jDownloader2, it didn't want to download the content that were on those links. Those links are direct downloads, so just opening one of those links will cause a download. Sorry, I'm new at this.

Comment: What? If they are direct download links then jDownloader will download whatever the link points to and nothing else.

Comment: @Ren your have to run that PS command from the folder where the "Sprite-urls.txt" file is. Or provide the full path: `Get-Content C:\Users\Ren\Desktop\Sprite-urls.txt | %{...}`